# Unexpected token when using switch?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Trying to use switch statement for rock paper scissors game, however keep getting ubexpected token and can't seem to figure out why :/. The console was highlighting the semi colon, so I removed those, but still no luck.

Before using the switch statement I tested the game in the console and it seemed to work fine.

```
const userScore = 0;
const computerScore = 0;
const userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
const scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector(".score-board");
const result_div = document.querySelector(".result");
const rock_div = document.getElementById("r");
const paper_div = document.getElementById("p");
const scissors_div = document.getElementById("s");
const lizard_div = document.getElementById("l");
const spock_div = document.getElementById("k");

function getComputerChoice() {
    const choices = ['r', 'p', 's', 'l', 'k'];
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    return choices[randomNumber];
}

function game(userChoice) {
    const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
        case "rs";
        case "rl";
        case "pr";
        case "pk";
        case "sp";
        case "sl";
        case "lk";
        case "lp";
        case "ks";
        case "kr";
            console.log("USER WINS");
            break;
        case "rk";
        case "rp";
        case "ps";
        case "pl";
        case "sr";
        case "sk";
        case "lr";
        case "ls";
        case "kp";
        case "kl";
            console.log("COMPUTER WINS");
            break;
        case "rr"
        case "pp"
        case "ss"
        case "ll"
        case "kk"
            console.log("Its a draw");
    }   
}

function main() {
    rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("r")
    })

    paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("p")
    })

    scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("s")
    })

    lizard_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("l")
    })

    spock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("k")
    })
}

    main();
```

I've tried searching around, but I see most of these errors were caused by people not using the swicth statement in their code,so decided to make my own post.

Comment: Shouldn't  case end with colon and not semicolons?

Comment: Good resource for researching method used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch. Shows the appropriate syntax

Answer (score 2):

The `case` parts of your `switch` statement need to end with a colon (`:`). Some of your `case`s end with a semicolon (`;`), and some end with nothing at all.

For example, replace `case "rs";` with `case "rs":`.

Additionally, your final `case` was missing a `break`.

```
const userScore = 0;
const computerScore = 0;
const userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
const scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector(".score-board");
const result_div = document.querySelector(".result");
const rock_div = document.getElementById("r");
const paper_div = document.getElementById("p");
const scissors_div = document.getElementById("s");
const lizard_div = document.getElementById("l");
const spock_div = document.getElementById("k");

function getComputerChoice() {
    const choices = ['r', 'p', 's', 'l', 'k'];
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    return choices[randomNumber];
}

function game(userChoice) {
    const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
        case "rs":
        case "rl":
        case "pr":
        case "pk":
        case "sp":
        case "sl":
        case "lk":
        case "lp":
        case "ks":
        case "kr":
            console.log("USER WINS");
            break;
        case "rk":
        case "rp":
        case "ps":
        case "pl":
        case "sr":
        case "sk":
        case "lr":
        case "ls":
        case "kp":
        case "kl":
            console.log("COMPUTER WINS");
            break;
        case "rr":
        case "pp":
        case "ss":
        case "ll":
        case "kk":
            console.log("Its a draw");
            break;
    }   
}

function main() {
    rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("r")
    })

    paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("p")
    })

    scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("s")
    })

    lizard_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("l")
    })

    spock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("k")
    })
}

    main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need colons, not semicolons.  See the docs for an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch